# Does my LINQ query provide distinct SampleNumbers based off the code and LINQPad output provided?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linqpad

I'm trying to use LINQPad to see outputs of my queries I'm writing for a C# WinForms application. I'm more just confused on how to interpret the outcome on a Dump() method and what is happening behind the scenes.My intended outcome is to have one SampleNumber per group of SampleData. SampleData is coming out of the database as a string split by commas.
Also, please spare me; I know how I name stuff is horrible and I'm planning to adjust once I get the data coming out correctly!

Here is my initial query:

```
var thinthroughoutQuery = (from a in ThicknessBlobs
                                       join b in SummaryDataItems on a.SampleNumber equals b.SampleNumber
                                       where (a.Source == "Thickness[0,0]")
                                       && b.TopBottomStatusFK == 3
                                       orderby a.PKId descending
                                       select a).Take(1000).ToList();
```

Here is where I attempt to take the string of SampleData, cut it at the delimiter, group by SampleNumber, and parse it as an integer:

```
var intThinThroughoutQuery = thinthroughoutQuery.Select(row => new { SampleNumber = row.SampleNumber, Value = row.SampleData.Split(",").Select(int.Parse) })
                .SelectMany(group => group.Value.Select(value => new { group.SampleNumber, SampleData = value })).ToArray();
```

Here is the output from using Dump() in LINQPad:

[image: Dump output from intThinThroughoutQuery]

To me, this appears like there are not distinct SampleNumbers and that each piece of SampleData separately maps to a repeating SampleNumber.

For further clarification, I want to be able to access the data and have it be like this:

[image: Intended output]

Rather than:

[image]

Comment: Seems you just want a group by : `var intThinThroughoutQuery = thinthroughoutQuery.Select(row => new { SampleNumber = row.SampleNumber, Value = row.SampleData.Split(",").Select(int.Parse) })
                .GroupBy(x => x.SampleNumber).ToArray();`

Comment: Aren't your original data in this format? Or `row.SampleNumber` is not unique?

Comment: @GuruStron The sample numbers are not unique, there are 3 of each SampleNumber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `GroupBy`/`ToLookup` after flattening with `SelectMany`:

```cs
var intThinThroughoutQuery = thinthroughoutQuery.Select(row => new { SampleNumber = row.SampleNumber, Value = row.SampleData.Split(",").Select(int.Parse) })
    .SelectMany(group => group.Value.Select(value => new { group.SampleNumber, SampleData = value }))
    .ToLookup(row => row.SampleNumber, row => row.SampleData);
```